# hazelcast client is not able connect to hazelcast server

Tags: hazelcast

1.hazelcast client is not able to connect to Hazelcast server  .

2.on console following message is shown :
INFO: hz.client_1 [simpleserver] [5.1.2] Trying to connect to [192.168.156.149]:5701

[hazelcast server hazelcast.xml and client code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qutoG.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Your server XML is 3.6, and the server is something in the 3.* series.

The client is 5.1.2.

See [here](https://docs.hazelcast.com/hazelcast/5.1/migrate/upgrading-from-imdg-4#version-compatibility) on compatibility.

Since newer is better, upgrade the server if you can.